# ajax returning 500 even after the controller has gotten all the data

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, hibernate

I have multiple ajax calls that used to return correctly to the javascript but now they return a 500 error. I am using java(hibernate) to get the data from the database and json to carry it back and forth between the javascript and java. The debug statements in the controller show me all my data is there ready to return to the ajax call.
I have double checked the DTO against all my resultclasses all fields are accounted for and datatypes match. Does anyone have any idea what to look for.

Comment: without any code its impossible to help you. Post some code

Comment: Probably something went wrong when the controller was returning the data to the client. Check the server logs.